# 3D viewing program in Scratch.mit rotation problem

Tags: mit-scratch

Whenever I rotate the object it squishes along either the x or z directions. I’m using this equation for the rotations.

x = x2*cosθ−y2*sinθ and y=x2*sinθ+y2*cosθ. x2=x*cosθ+ysinθ and y2=−x*sinθ+y*cosθ.

θ is the angle you are setting it to.

I tried making a second list for each coordinate line but it gave me me problems like *possible 4d rotations*

Comment: Could you please give us the project link?

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you apply the equations may be why your code stretches the object. I was able to successfully create a function in my [Scratch project](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/566517935/) which applies the 3 separate rotations to a 3D point. It uses the following function to apply the rotation:

[image: a picture of the code]

Here is an example of using the function to rotate a point:

[image]